# Is there a way in YouTrack to query for all linked issues where some attribute as a value?

Tags: youtrack, youtrack-api

In our YouTrack our epics has a field call `Lead` which is assigned to a user. Then subtasks of that epic are assigned to different people.

If I query `#Lead: me` it will show all epics that I am assigned, but it does not show the subtasks that are assigned to other people because the subtasks don't have me as the lead.

In order to see all the subtasks, I have to run the first query then type `Links: <ticket id>,<ticket id>....`

Is there any query so that I can see all tickets that link to the tickets that I am the lead? That way I don't have to do the first query, then do the second query?

Answer (score 1):

> If I query #Lead: me

if the field name is `Lead`, it should be just `Lead:me` without `#`

As for the question itself, you can try `Lead:me OR Subtask of {Lead:me}`.

More details are available in the [search query doc](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/youtrack/server/Search-and-Command-Attributes.html).